# Integration of Spark2.0 and cassandra using R

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, sparkr

Currently we are migrating the hive persistence store to Cassandra cluster.We have been using Spark 2.0 and sparkR framework to run our analytics report.We have just started with Cassandra integration and we would appreciate some sample code to initiate the spark session from within an R module.We would also need help on additional input on optimizing such integration at spark 2.0 run time.

Comment: What is the question here? What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: I would need the basic steps to be followed to setup the spark R environment  using Cassandra connector and query Cassandra tables using spark SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow [Spark R documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#from-data-sources), use correct [Spark packages](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) to connect to Cassandra, and s[etup necessary properties](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md):

Start R with Spark support:

```sh
SPARK_HOME=`pwd` R
```

Load Spark R library:

```r
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
```

Initialize Spark session:

```r
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]",
  sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g", 
                     spark.cassandra.connection.host = "IP"),
  sparkPackages = "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.4.0")
```

`spark.cassandra.connection.host` need to point to Cassandra host.  The value of `sparkPackages` may depend on the version of Spark you're using - does it use Scala 2.10 or 2.11, etc. See connector documentation for more details.

Read data:

```r
df <-read.df(source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra", keyspace = "test", table = "tm2")
```

and just work with them:

```r
> head(df)
  id          d                  ts
1  1 2019-07-10 2019-07-18 11:56:16
2  2 2019-07-18 2019-07-18 11:03:10
```

You can save data into Cassandra table the same way as for other sources - just need to use correct source: `source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra"`