# how to read/write sparkR and sparklyr dataframe from/to casandara and S3?

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, sparkr

I have a spark data frame, I want to save this data frame as a table in Casandra and save as parquet in S3. everywhere python, java, scala codes are there. I'm not finding the right solution in R.
I have found `Rcasandra`  package can i use this to do the same?

Comment: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601715/integration-of-spark2-0-and-cassandra-using-r/57107100#57107100 - I can't point to it via close because it's not accepted... `Rcassandra` is for direct access from R, not from Spark. I wrote a note to add this to official SCC documentation

Comment: In RCasandra im not able to connect only.

Comment: RCassandra is thrift-based and shouldn't be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811330/cassandra-database-is-not-connecting-with-r-via-rcassandra/53970313#53970313 if you use Spark, just follow instructions in the first link